# Как хранить в базе данных ссылки на изображения

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, изображения, phpmyadmin

Как занести в базу ссылку на изображение я знаю. Как сделать, чтобы администратор блога мог добавлять изображение для статьи через форму? (То есть чтобы не приходилось прописывать ссылку на изображение).

Comment: советую присмотреться к визуальним редакторам как например visavi или imperavi. Вы с их помощью и картинку вставите и сможете не используя теги визуально оформлять ваши статьи

Comment: Как вариант, можно создать папку с ресурсами и выкладывать все картинки туда

Answer (score 1):

По-любому в базе данных лучше хранить только имена файлов (пример `file_name.jpg`).

А полный путь прописывать уже через `php` (пример `http://mysite.ru/images/` или `./images/`)

Очень полезная библиотека **ajaxupload.js** - тут пример ее работы: http://ajaxs.ru/demo/ajax/imageload/.

Источник: http://gist.github.com/HarpreetChamdal/3369391.

Можно и через jquery: https://agentejo.com/blog/ajaxupload.js-ajaxify-your-forms-and-file-uploads

```
$(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'upload-file.php',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // extension is not allowed 
                    status.text('Поддерживаемые форматы JPG, PNG или GIF');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Загрузка...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('');
                //Add uploaded file to list
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text('Файл не загружен' + file).addClass('error');
                }
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Это я уже понял,а можно как то сделать чтобы через <input type="file" пользователь заносил картинку,а я в свою очередь помещал ее в какуюто папку и в бд записывал путь к данному файлу?

Comment: Очень полезная библиотека **ajaxupload.js** - тут пример ее работы: http://ajaxs.ru/demo/ajax/imageload/.

Источник: https://gist.github.com/HarpreetChamdal/3369391.

Можно и через jquery: https://agentejo.com/blog/ajaxupload.js-ajaxify-your-forms-and-file-uploads

Comment: Ну я понял что оно будет работать без перезагрузки странички,а как мне взять путь к файлу?

Comment: Может я немного глупый но у меня проблема в том чтобы понять как мне считать путь к файлу с изображения которое разместил юзер.

Comment: С чего ты взял что ты глупый. Может я глупый, не понимаю вопрос :)

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov когда ты выкладываешь файл он присылается на сервер, сервер это обрабатывает, ты сам решаешь в какую это папку положить через код